# OPGP: tag8 being converted to tag11, part of 4880 spec?

Tags: pgp

When a tag8 compressed data packet does not contain compressed data i've seen some products simply handle the packet as a tag11 literal data packet, yet i find nothing in the 4880 spec old/new suggesting this is an acceptable behavior. what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a Bouncy Castle issue that has been fixed in versions since 2.3.2. Basically a rogue Tag08 compressed data packet (old format xA3) was immediately followed by a byte of binary zeros, which was followed by xCB - a new format tag0D packet hdr. The trick was identifying this string and then skipping past the garbage Tag08 hdr.

For more information on this bug... https://www.bouncycastle.org/releasenotes.html  and  https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/1027
HTH,
mvh